# AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options'

Tags: python, dask, distributed, attributeerror

I'm a rookie using Dask and I installed the new version 2.12.0 on my MacBook MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6. When I try to start the distributed mode with the code below:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client()
```

I got the following **error**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-67101dbde0b6> in <module>()
      1 from dask.distributed import Client
----> 2 c = Client()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in __init__(self, address, loop, timeout, set_as_default, scheduler_file, security, asynchronous, name, heartbeat_interval, **kwargs)
    554         if set_as_default:
    555             self._previous_get = _globals.get('get')
--> 556             dask.set_options(get=self.get)
    557             self._previous_shuffle = _globals.get('shuffle')
    558             dask.set_options(shuffle='tasks')

AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options'
```

Also, if I instantiate the `c = Client(set_as_default=False)` the cluster seems to successfully raise because I get the connection information for the dashboard ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8Hr.png)). But as I navigate through the dashboard the [following error is triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJN9t.png).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html) lifting a single machine cluster seems to be trivial but I don't know what could be wrong. I would be very grateful if someone could guide me on how to solve this incident ;)

Comment: Just to check, what is the name of your python module containing `c = Client()`?

Comment: Hi @dspencer, I imported that module through:

```from dask.distributed import Client```

Comment: I mean, what is the name of the python script you are running? I just want to make sure that it is not `dask.py`

Comment: Yes @dspencer, the module name was ```dask.py```. I renamed the module by another but the error persists: ```AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options'```.

Comment: How did you install `dask`? You should use `pip install dask[complete]` to install everything

Answer (score 2):

Your source file is named `dask.py`, which introduces a naming conflict between your module, `dask.py`, and the `dask` package, with your module taking precedence in later import statements. Therefore, when `distributed/client.py` attempts to call `dask.set_options`, this fails with `AttributeError` as your module does not provide this function.

After running this `dask.py` module, python caches the compiled python code. Therefore, even when you renamed your module to something else, the import name conflict still exists. To resolve this, you should delete the `__pycache__` directory after which you should find that your module executes successfully.

Comment: Thanks @dspencer. I removed the ```__pycache__``` folder and works!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check out [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that we can mark this question as answered.